# Pass pipeline variable from Designer to YAML job template

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I initially wanted to define pipeline variables in my `azure-pipelines.yml` that I can optionally set at queue time, but it seems that this is not supported at the moment: variables that can be set at queue time can only be defined in the Designer. This variable (comma-separated) is named `nx_versions` and will be used to build a matrix strategy. Here's a minimal example:

```
# azure-pipelines.yml
jobs:
- template: job-template.yml
  parameters:
    nx_versions: $(nx_versions)
```

and

```
# job-template.yml
parameters:
  nx_versions: 
    - 1

jobs:
  - job: build
    strategy:
      matrix:
        ${{ each nxver in parameters.nx_versions }}:
          NX_${{ nxver }}:
            NXVersion: ${{ nxver }}
    steps:
      - powershell: echo $(NXVersion)
```

Queuing the build with `nx_versions = 2,3` (value doesn't actually matter) results in an error:

```
/job-template.yml (Line: 9, Col: 9): Expected a sequence or mapping. Actual value '$(nx_versions)'
```

Is this even possible? I also tried using `${{ nx_versions }}` and `${{ variables.nx_versions }}` to no avail.

This is possible with a full Designer solution.

Comment: I haven't tried it by myself, but have you also tried the runtime expression format?
$[variables.var] 
as stated here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#understand-variable-syntax

Answer (score 3):

The trivial pipeline (not referencing templates, but could be extended easily to do so)

```
parameters:
- name: nx_versions
  type: object
  default: 
  - 1
  - 4

jobs:
  - job: build
    strategy:
      matrix:
        ${{ each nxver in parameters.nx_versions }}:
          NX_${{ nxver }}:
            NXVersion: ${{ nxver }}
    steps:
      - powershell: echo $(NXVersion)
```

Expands to

```
parameters:
- name: nx_versions
  type: object
  default:
  - 1
  - 4
stages:
- stage: __default
  jobs:
  - job: build
    strategy:
      matrix:
        NX_1:
          NXVersion: 1
        NX_4:
          NXVersion: 4
    steps:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      inputs:
        targetType: inline
        script: echo $(NXVersion)
```

If you go to queue a build for that, you get a parameters page with the defaults:

[image: Defaults]

that you can override:

[image: Override parameters]

which results in:

[image: Overridden job result]

Answer (score 0):

I am running into the same issue. I don't think this is currently possible. I believe this is being worked on https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/pull/129