# how can we pass variable as a parameters(as a list)

Tags: bash, arraylist, azure-devops, yaml, parameter-passing

Can we pass variable as a parameters(as a list)?

Below code is not working. That means it is not taking it as a list , it is taking it as a one parameter as whole string.
For example :

We have $(templateParm) = dir1/dir2, dir3/dir4

- -template: dockerBuild.yml

  parameters:

  ```
    DOCKER_FILE: [ "$(templateParm)" ]
    SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME: $(Build.SourceBranchName)
    BUILD_NUMBER: $(Build.BuildNumber)
    SOURCE_DIR: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
  ```

If we pass the value here like below, it is taking it as a list. That means it is taking it as 2 parameters.

- -template: dockerBuild.yml

  parameters:

  ```
    DOCKER_FILE: [ "dir1/dir2", "dir3/dir4" ]
    SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME: $(Build.SourceBranchName)
    BUILD_NUMBER: $(Build.BuildNumber)
    SOURCE_DIR: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
  ```

is there any solution?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. `TemplateParam` will be always a string. But you can try a different approach.

If you define your template in this way:

```yaml
#template.yaml
parameters:
- name: 'DOCKER_FILES'
  type: object
  default: {}
- name: 'server'
  type: string
  default: ''

steps:
- ${{ each dockerFile in parameters.DOCKER_FILES }}:
  - script: echo ${{ parameters.server }}:${{ dockerFile }}
```

and build in this

```yaml
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- template: template.yaml
  parameters:
    DOCKER_FILES: 
    - "dir1/dir2"
    - "dir3/dir4"
    server: someServer
```

However in this case you still need to put them separetly. Variables are considered as string at least at the moment.

I tried also this approach: [Pass pipeline variable from Designer to YAML job template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55228903/pass-pipeline-variable-from-designer-to-yaml-job-template) but I got the same result.

**EDIT**

This below doesn't work. I only wanted to show what I tried to save your time.

And I tried sth like this:

```yaml
variables:
- name: templateParam
  value: "dir1/dir2,dir3/dir4"

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
        $array = $variable.Split(',)
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=templateParamArray]$array"
- template: template.yaml
  parameters:
    instances: 
    ${{ each s in templateParamArray }}:
      - ${{ s }}:
    server: someServer
```

But without success. You can be interested also on this [developer community topic](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/625116/iterative-insertion-in-azure-pipelines-yaml-should.html).

To sum up, I think that it is not possible at the moment what you want to achieve, having list in one variable.

Comment: I wasn't clear enough. It is not possible to have array in variable. I just showed above what I tried to save your time. Only first part is working where you have separate items. Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: Thanks Krzysztof Madej, but we are facing some issue while using instances.we are passing parameters in 
parms=dir1/dir2,dir3/dir4

Passing params as enviromental variable

echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=templateParm]$parms"

- template: template.yaml

      parameters:

        DOCKER_FILE: 
          ${{ each s in templateParm }}:
          - ${{ s }}:
        BUILD_NUMBER: $(Build.BuildNumber)
        SOURCE_DIR: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)

output: Unrecognized value: 'templateParm'. Located at position 1 within expression: templateParm.
can you please suggest !!

Comment: Thanks bro  Krzysztof Madej

Comment: I would recommend to keep you them in separate variables and use this:
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- template: template.yaml
  parameters:
    DOCKER_FILES: 
    - "dir1/dir2"
    - "dir3/dir4"
    server: someServer

Comment: but prob is variables are not fixed, it comes dynamically when there is change in folder. So how can we separate them?

Comment: Why do you mean by saysing dynamic. You run the pipeline and pipeline will generate you a new folders and thus you need to get this at runtime. Or you mean that this changes often, and you want to avoid pipeline modifications?